# asterisk color in red using textinputlayout in android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Is it possible to make just the asterisk in the hint red when using a TextInputLayout from the design support library? I tried many things but color of asterisk keeps changing from red to theme color when it changes to floating label. Please help me as I am stuck here.Thanks

[image: Want like this]

[image: Happens like this]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `EditText` hint from string file. Add below code in String file and set it in your `EditText`

```
<string name="hint_name">Your Hint<font color='@android:color/red'><sup>*</sup></font></string>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried this:

1) Put this bit of code in your string.xml file

```
    <string name="string_name">My String<font color="#ff0000">
<bold>*</bold></font></string>
```

2) and then in your xml:

```
android:hint="@string/string_name"
```

Or you can use SpannableStringBuilder too if you want.

Comment: I tried your way but its not working and as for SpannableStringBuilder I tried it too but when focus is on edittext and hint is converted to label color of star is changed to theme color instead of red.